# C# Memory - Get the final PointerAddress x64 binary

Tags: c#, memory

I'm getting a BaseAddress from a x64 binary process using the following function:

```
public static long GetBaseAddress(string ProcessName, string ModuleName)
{
    try
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName);
        ProcessModuleCollection modules = processes[0].Modules;
        ProcessModule DLLBaseAddress = null;

        foreach (ProcessModule i in modules)
        {
            if (i.ModuleName == ModuleName)
            {
                DLLBaseAddress = i;
            }
        }

        return DLLBaseAddress.BaseAddress.ToInt64();
    }
    catch
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

After receiving the BaseAddress, I'm trying to get the PointerAdress using the following function:

```
public static int GetPointerAddress(int Pointer, int[] Offset)
{
    byte[] Buffer = new byte[4];

    ReadProcessMemory(GetProcessHandle(), Pointer, Buffer, Buffer.Length);

    for (int x = 0; x < (Offset.Length - 1); x++)
    {
        Pointer = BitConverter.ToInt32(Buffer, 0) + Offset[x];
        ReadProcessMemory(GetProcessHandle(), Pointer, Buffer, Buffer.Length);
    }

    Pointer = BitConverter.ToInt32(Buffer, 0) + Offset[Offset.Length - 1];

    return Pointer;
}
```

which is still set to a x32 binary way, how could I redo this function to use it with a x64 binary process?

I've been trying the following:

```
public static long GetPointerAddress(long Pointer, int[] Offset)
{
    byte[] Buffer = new byte[8];

    ReadProcessMemory(GetProcessHandle(), Pointer, Buffer, Buffer.Length);

    for (int x = 0; x < (Offset.Length - 1); x++)
    {
        Pointer = BitConverter.ToInt64(Buffer, 0) + Offset[x];
        ReadProcessMemory(GetProcessHandle(), Pointer, Buffer, Buffer.Length);
    }

    Pointer = BitConverter.ToInt64(Buffer, 0) + Offset[Offset.Length - 1];

    return Pointer;
}
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: You need to read 8 bytes, not 4.  The odds that this will come to a good end are very low, a 64-bit process uses a high entropy variant of ASLR (address space layout randomization), makes it hard to guess at correct offsets.  Especially so when the only thing you know is a code address but are looking for data.  Best to give up early.

Answer (score 0):

32 bit binary process cannot reflect on 64 bit binary process like that. You must write your own code as 64 bit if you expect ReadProcessMemory() to work.